# Default Value for datetime2

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, datetime2

What is the default value for datetime2?

Edited: Sorry maybe I explain me wrong, I've tried to insert getDate() and it save me this value.

I need to know what is the value in this field (red one) of my ssms

[image: EXAMPLE]

Comment: You have to specify a column's default value!

Comment: Post the code for your GETDATE() test.

Comment: The [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime2-transact-sql) lists the default value for each type. What this actually *means* however is often unclear. In this case, I believe it's the value you'll obtain if you try to cast or convert an *empty string* to `datetime2`.

Comment: Your question is still unclear here. What do you mean it "saved you this value"? The box you've highlighted is the default value, it's not a stored value. Stored values are returned by using a `SELECT` statement.

Answer (score 6):

Everything in SQL Server has a default value of *`NULL`* unless you specify otherwise. For example `DECLARE @MyDate datetime2(0);`: `@MyDate` will have a value of *`NULL`*.

As for tables:

```
CREATE TABLE #Sample (MyDate datetime2(0),
                      MyDate2 datetime2(0) DEFAULT GETDATE(),
                      MyDate3 datetime2(0) DEFAULT '20000101');
```

The column `MyDate` will have a default value of *`NULL`*, `MyDate2` will be `GETDATE()` (which is the current date and time when the row was created). Finally `MyDate3` will have a default value of 01 January 2000.

Stored Procedures/Functions work slight differently:

```
CREATE PROC ReturnDate @MyDate datetime2(0), @MyDate2 datetime2(0) = NULL, @MyDate3 = '20000101' AS...
```

Here, `@MyDate` has no default value, thus it **must** have a value supplied to be able to use the Procedure. `@MyDate2`, however, has a default value of *`NULL`*, thus doesn't need to be supplied and the value *`NULL`* will be used. If a value for `@MyDate2` is supplied, that supplied value will be used. `@MyDate3` has a default value of 01 January 2000, thus if the parameter isn't specified then the default value will be used.

*Edit: it's worth noting that if you pass `NULL` in an `INSERT` statement to a table, or SP/Function, with a default value (that isn't `NULL`) then `NULL` will be used. It is only if the column/parameter is omitted from the `INSERT`/`EXEC`/etc statement that the default value will be used.*

Comment: The SQL Server documentation lists default values for many datatypes and the values listed aren't `NULL`. So whilst *you* may consider them to all have a default value of `NULL`, that's not what is documented. See e.g. link in comment to question.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Yes, that article is specifically talking about from other default values. For example, it states that if only a date is passed, the time portion will default to `'00:00:00'` or if only a time is passed, the date defaults to `'1900-01-01'`. If you have a table, with a `datetime2` then the default value will be what ever you specified. You can run the `CREATE` statement i provided above and test with that table if you wish to test. :)

Comment: I've changed the image

Comment: Instead of GetDate, you should use  SYSDATETIME()

Comment: @CaM that's a preference thing.

Comment: @ThomA I think in this case CaM's preference is better because SYSDATETIME() returns a DateTime2 (more prevision than a DateTime), and GETDATE() returns a DateTime; you've got a DateTime2 in the column, why would you prefer less precision?

Comment: The above is using a `datetime2(0)`, @DanielJamesBryars . Both `GETDATE()` and `SYSDATETIME()` return a higher accuracy than they can store.

Comment: @ThomA oh I see, got it. datetime2 [ (fractional seconds precision) ]

Answer (score 1):

If you need to specify the default value you should use that format : '9999-12-31 23:59:59.9999999'

If you need UTC Now, you should use getutcdate()

https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3OiS.png

Answer (score 1):

In the [Microsoft Documentation for datetime2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime2-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), it shows that the default value for datetime2 is

'1900-01-01 00:00:00'

It's four years late, but I hope it helps others down the line.

Answer (score 0):

The default value is  '1900-01-01 00:00:00.0000000' in SQL Server but when you try from EntityFramework it comes '0001-01-01 00:00:00.0000000' and to achieve this you put your code like this :

the datetime variable or value should be assigned ''

```
@AssetCode nvarchar(100)='',  
@AssignedToDept nvarchar(100)='',
@AssignedToDeptDate datetime2(7)='',
@AssignedToOwnerDate datetime2(7)='',
@CreatedBy nvarchar(100)='',
@CreatedDate datetime2(7)='',
@CreatedMode nvarchar(100)='',
@Description nvarchar(max)='',
@IsClosed bit=false,
@IsDeleted bit=false,
@IsDeletedBy nvarchar(100)='',
@OwnerId nvarchar(100)='',
@PersonEmail nvarchar(100)='',
@PersonName nvarchar(100)='',
@PersonPhone nvarchar(100)='',
@Priority int=4,
@Subject nvarchar(100)='',
@TicketNumber nvarchar(450)='',
@TicketStatus nvarchar(100)='',
@TicketType nvarchar(100)='',
@UpdatedDate datetime2(7)='',
@UpdatedBy nvarchar(100)=''

set @TicketNumber='IN00000361'
INSERT INTO [dbo].[TblTickets]([TicketNumber], [TicketType], [Subject], 
[Description], [Priority], [CreatedDate], [CreatedBy], [CreatedMode], [PersonPhone], 
[PersonName], [PersonEmail], [UpdatedDate], [UpdatedBy], [AssignedToDept], 
[AssignedToDeptDate], 
[OwnerId], [AssignedToOwnerDate], [IsClosed], [IsDeleted], [IsDeletedBy], 
[TicketStatus], [AssetCode])
VALUES( @TicketNumber, @TicketType, @Subject, @Description, @Priority, 
@CreatedDate, @CreatedBy, @CreatedMode, @PersonPhone, @PersonName, 
@PersonEmail, @UpdatedDate, @UpdatedBy, @AssignedToDept, @AssignedToDeptDate,
@OwnerId, @AssignedToOwnerDate, @IsClosed, @IsDeleted, 
@IsDeletedBy, @TicketStatus, @AssetCode)
```

So the output be like this

```
Id  TicketNumber    TicketType  Subject Description Priority    CreatedDate CreatedBy
CreatedMode PersonPhone PersonName  PersonEmail UpdatedDate UpdatedBy   AssignedToDept
AssignedToDeptDate  OwnerId AssignedToOwnerDate IsClosed    IsDeleted
IsDeletedBy TicketStatus    AssetCode
24  IN00000361              4   1900-01-01 00:00:00.0000000
1900-01-01 00:00:00.0000000         1900-01-01 00:00:00.0000000
1900-01-01 00:00:00.0000000 0   0
```

Also when you look up for your record the query is
select * from TblTickets where UpdatedDate = ''